# Python: Do I need to catch EINTR in a pipe-reading loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe, system-calls, eintr

#### tl;dr

Should I handle EINTR "system call interrupted" errors when reading a pipe in Python, and if so, how do I test such code?

#### Description

In the traceback below, `self._dataq` is a `multiprocessing.Queue` (technically, I'm using the `billiard` library, but I think they're basically the same code). A Python subprocess occasionally writes to the other end of the queue. I think what happened is that a system call was reading the pipe that feeds the queue, and a signal arrived -- possibly a SIGINT from a second Ctrl+C event (the first SIGINT occurred where you see the user's `^C` on the second line of the logging output, and my signal handler caught that SIGINT, as you can see in the WARNING message in the log).

```
[INFO     2014-03-05 14:16:06,000] Doing some work, la-dee-da
^C[WARNING 2014-03-05 14:16:07,344] Commencing shutdown. (Signal SIGINT, process 2469.). Press Ctrl+C again to exit immediately.
[DEBUG    2014-03-05 14:16:07,347] Terminating subprocess
Traceback (most recent call last):
[... a bunch of stuff omitted]
  File "mycode.py", line 97, in __next__
    result = self._dataq.get(timeout=0.1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/queues.py", line 103, in get
    if timeout < 0 or not self._poll(timeout):
IOError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call
```

The statement `result = self._dataq.get(timeout=0.1)` in the traceback above is in the middle of a loop that looks like the following. The main purpose of the loop is so that I can give up trying to read from `self._dataq` when `self.timedout()` starts returning `True`.

```python
import queue
while True:
    try:
        result = self._dataq.get(timeout=0.1)
    except queue.Empty:
        if self.timedout():
            self.close()
            raise MyTimedoutError()
    else:
        break
```

#### Question

If my theory about why the `IOError` occurred is correct, then the `try`...`except` block above should catch and ignore `IOError`s when they're caused by interrupted system calls. If it is a signal that caused the EINTR error, than the mere act of coming back into Python to run the `except IOError:` statement would allow Python-level signal handlers to run.

Is that correct? If so, is it possible to test this change in my code? It's not obvious to me how I would write a unit test that wouldn't contain a severe race condition.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.5 solves this problem by putting the responsibility for dealing with `EINTR` on the Python runtime instead of on application code. See [PEP 475](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/) and the [Python 3.5 Changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/changelog.html#id62).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to call this a bug in Python.  I cannot find any documentation that [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) is allowed to raise `IOError` on `EINTR` (though it would make sense to raise on other I/O issues, which is why **you should check the errno** attribute of the raised exception before ignoring it; see [`errno`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html)), and it doesn't directly map to any low-level C function which would provide such behavior.  There was [some discussion](http://bugs.python.org/issue18885) of handling all `EINTR`s at the C level, but that didn't make it into 3.4 (and I doubt it will make it into 2.x at all), so this is probably still fair game to report.